# Run same function on multiples columns and return a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns in a dataframe that have the values Green/ Yellow/ Red:

Sample:

| Date | Index1 | Index2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20-Dec-21 | Green | Yellow |
| 21-Dec-21 | Red | Yellow |

I want to add one more column to this dataframe that first assigns a score to each column based on the logic: Score = 1 if Green, 0.5 if Yellow, 0 if Red and then adds these individual scores to produce a final score. Eg. for Row 1, score = 1+0.5 = 1.5, for row 2 score = 0+0.5 =0.5 and so on.

The func itself is easy to write:

```
def color_to_score(x):
    if (x=='Green'):
        return 1
    elif (x=='Yellow'):
        return 0.5
    else: return 0
```

But I am struggling to apply this to each column and then adding the resulting score across columns to produce a new one in an elegant way.
I can obviously do something like:

```
df['Index1score'] = df['Index1'].apply(color_to_score)
```

to produce a score column for each of the relevant columns and then add them but that is very inelegant and not scalable. Looking for help.

Comment: Why do you think that's "inelegant and not scalable"?  I disagree with both assertions.  You have one statement creating an entire new column from existing data.

Comment: you could use `replace`; e.g. `df['Index1score'] = df['Index1'].replace({'Green': 1, 'Yellow': 0.5, 'Red': 0}, regex=True)`

Comment: So for the final (composite) score, I can say something like:

```
df['score'] = (df['Index1'].apply(color_to_score) + df['Index1'].apply(color_to_score)) + .....

```
but once the # of columns go beyond a certain no, this solution is not v elegant. So may be there's a trick I am missing here to specify all the column names together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `replace()`:

```
replace_dict = {'Green':1,'Yellow':.5,'\w':0}
df.assign(new_col = df[['col1','col2']].replace(replace_dict,regex=True).sum(axis=1))
```

Also, instead of using `\w` to replace all other words with 0, you could use `pd.to_numeric()` and set `errors = 'coerce'` to convert all non numeric values to `NaN`

```
replace_dict = {'Green':1,'Yellow':.5}
df.assign(new_col = pd.to_numeric(df[['col1','col2']].replace(replace_dict).stack(),errors='coerce').unstack().sum(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
        Date   col1    col2  new_col
0  20-Dec-21  Green  Yellow      1.5
1  21-Dec-21    Red  Yellow      0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to supply Axis=1 to apply the function to each row.
   2.`x` in your function would be a row (not a cell).
2. You can convert `x`, the row, to a list.
3. Count how many times each value is in the list, and multiply it by its value.
4. Sum, and output the result.

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easy by choosing Python over pandas.

```
score_dict = {'Green': 1, 'Yellow': 0.5, 'Red': 0}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["total_score"] = 0.0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.at[index, "total_score"] = score_dict[row["Index1"]] + score_dict[row["Index2"]]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with this solution.

```
scores = []
for index in range(len(df.index)):
    scoreTotal = 0
    for column in df.columns:
        color = df[column][index]
        scoreTotal += color_to_score(color)

    scores.append(scoreTotal)

df["Score"] = scores
```